# Ruby regexp handling of nbsp

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.0

In ruby 1.9.3 the regex engine doesn't treat nbsp's (\u00A0) as a space (\s). This is often a bummer for me.

So my question is, will this change in 2.0? If not, is there any way to monkey patch a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Unicode properties (you need to declare a matching source code encoding for this to work):

```
# encoding=utf-8 
if subject ~= /\p{Z}/
    # subject contains whitespace or other separators
```

or use POSIX character classes:

```
if subject ~= /[[:space:]]/
```

According to [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html), `\s` will only match `[ \t\r\n\f]` now and in the future.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the \p{Z} is interesting. Can you explain what you mean by other separators?

Comment: @pguardiario: Sorry, I somehow missed your comment. The Unicode standard defines many other separators that appear to be used primarily in Eastern languages where words are not necessarily visibly separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, I recommend using the Unicode character class of "**Space separators**" `\p{Zs}`:

```
/\p{Zs}/u  =~  "\xC2\xA0"
/\p{Zs}/u  =~  "\u00A0"
/\p{Zs}/u  =~  HTMLEntities.new.decode('&nbsp;')
```

See the Ruby-documentation for more [Unicode character properties](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

Note: Make sure, that your input-string is valid UTF-8 encoding. There are non-breaking spaces in other encodings too, e.g. "\xA0" in ISO-8859-1 (Latin1). [More info on the "non-breaking space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

FYI: In most RegExp flavors and programming languages that support Unicode, character class `\s` usually includes all characters from the Unicode "separator" property `\p{Z}` (as mentioned by Tim Pietcker); However, **Java** and **Ruby** are popular exceptions here and `\s` only matches `[ \t\r\n\f]`.