# Dealing with special character in Nokogiri / Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I am getting the text from the body of an HTML doc as below. When I try to regex scan for the term "Exhibit 99", I get an no matched, i.e, an empty array. However, in the html, I do see "Exhibit 99", although inspect element shows it with &nbsp99. How can I get rid of these HTML characters and search for "Exhibit 99" as if it were a regular string?

```
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1467373/000146737316000912/fy16q3plc8-kbody.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
body = doc.css("body").text
body.scan(/exhibit 99/i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unicode character space

You can use :

```
body.scan(/exhibit\p{Zs}99/i)
```

From the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html) about `Unicode character’s General Category`:

```
/\p{Z}/ - 'Separator'
/\p{Zs}/ - 'Separator: Space'
```

It matches a whitespace or a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), but no tab or newline. The string should be encoded in UTF-8. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287701/ruby-regexp-handling-of-nbsp) for more information.

## non-word character

A more permissive regex would be :

```
body.scan(/exhibit\W99/i)
```

This allows any character other than a letter, a digit or an underscore between `exhibit` and `99`. It would match a whitespace, a nbsp, a tab, a dash, ...

Comment: That works. Can you please explain what that piece of code is doing?